# Locking a DevExpress DockLayoutManager

Tags: wpf, devexpress

Is it possible to lock the components of a DevExpress `DockLayoutManager` (WPF)? I want to make layout changes optional so the user doesn't accidentally undock components. `IsEnabled` doesn't work because it disables all child components completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can do this only through your `BaseLayoutItem`s' `Allow*` properties. So now I recurse through all my `LayoutGroup`s and their `Items` and set `AllowFloat`, `AllowDrag`, `AllowMaximize`, `AllowHide`, `AllowMove`, `AllowSizing` to `true` or `false`, respectively.